# How to manage Huge operations on MySql

Tags: database, mysql, database-optimization

I have a MySql DataBase. I have a lot of records (about *4,000,000,000* rows) and I want to process them in order to reduce them(reduce to about *1,000,000,000* Rows).

Assume I have following tables:

- table **RawData**: I have more than 5000 rows per sec that I want to insert them to RawData
- table **ProcessedData** : this table is a processed(aggregated) storage for rows that were inserted at RawData.
       *minimum rows count > 20,000,000*
- table **ProcessedDataDetail**: I write details of table ProcessedData (data that was aggregated )

  users want to view and search in **ProcessedData** table that need to join more than **8** other tables.
  Inserting in RawData and searching in ProcessedData (ProcessedData INNER JOIN ProcessedDataDetail INNER JOIN ...) are very slow. I used a lot of Indexes. assume my data length is 1G, but my Index length is 4G :). ( I want to get ride of these indexes, they make slow my process)

How can I Increase speed of this process ?

I think I need a shadow table from **ProcessedData**, name it **ProcessedDataShadow**. then proccess RawData and aggregate them with **ProcessedDataShadow**, then insert the result in **ProcessedDataShadow** and **ProcessedData**. What is your idea??

(I am developing the project by C++)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about what your actual application is, I have these suggestions:

1. Use InnoDB if you aren't already. InnoDB makes use of row-locks and are much better at handling concurrent updates/inserts. It will be slower if you don't work concurrently, but the row-locking is probably a must have for you, depending on how many sources you will have for RawData.
2. Indexes usually speeds up things, but badly chosen indexes can make things slower. I don't think you want to get rid of them, but a lot of indexes can make inserts very slow. It is possible to disable indexes when inserting batches of data, in order to prevent updating indexes on each insert.
3. If you will be selecting huge amount of data that might disturb the data collection, consider using a replicated slave database server that you use only for reading. Even if that will lock rows /tables, the primary (master) database wont be affected, and the slave will get back up to speed as soon as it is free to do so.
4. Do you need to process data in the database? If possible, maybe collect all data in the application and only insert ProcessedData.

Comment: thanks a lot.but I have problem with InnoDB in inserting. why it insert records slowly ?

Comment: Inserts with InnoDB is much slower than MyISAM, because of the concurrency support. However, when comparing inserting into one table, on 10 simultaneous connections at once, InnoDB would probably be faster or atleast equally fast, so it all depends on application. You might speed up the process by inserting multiple rows at the same time (meaning, multiple VALUES parenthesis)

Comment: This ca be worth reading as well: http://tag1consulting.com/InnoDB_Performance_Tuning

Answer (score 2):

You've not said what the structure of the data is, how its consolidated, how promptly data needs to be available to users nor how lumpy the consolidation process can be.

However the most immediate problem will be sinking 5000 rows per second. You're going to need a very big, very fast machine (probably a sharded cluster).

If possible I'd recommend writing a consolidating buffer (using an in-memory hash table - not in the DBMS) to put the consolidated data into - even if it's only partially consolidated - then update from this into the processedData table rather than trying to populate it directly from the rawData.

Indeed, I'd probably consider seperating the raw and consolidated data onto seperate servers/clusters (the MySQL federated engine is handy for providing a unified view of the data).

Have you analysed your queries to see which indexes you really need? (hint - [this script](http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/) is very useful for this).